# audit/monitor writes and updates to data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replication

I have a replication environment where one site is used just to read from.
I have the application working with both sites and I want to make sure it doesn't write the second site.
any idea how can I trace only inserts and updates done except for the replication itself ? 
will auditing give me a good solution for this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `Tigger` on each table `Instead of Insert,Update`

you can `raiserror` based on circumstances